# Creating a CSS grid layout that auto adjusts to text content

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I'm trying to create a header component, something like the below image - a centred title, and a back button on the left.

[image: illustration showing header with centred title and back button on left]

I figured the best way to achieve this was with a CSS grid layout using 3 columns, illustrated below. These are shown at widths of 25% / 50% / 25% respectively.

[image: illustration showing grid layout]

The problem is I want things to adjust automatically depending on the text length.

There are essentially 3 conditions that need to be met.

**Condition 1:**

A longer title should fill available space, before cutting off with an ellipsis.

[image]

[image]

**Condition 2:**

If both text fields are too long, then cut off both at the preferred layout (25% / 50% / 25%)

[image]

**Condition 3:**

a longer back button should fill available space, before cutting off with an ellipsis

[image]

[image]

I am, however, struggling to meet all 3 conditions. Perhaps it's not even possible without some JS, but I'm hoping it is.

I've attached a code snippet which which meets conditions 1 and 2, but not 3.

Is anyone able to solve this problem with CSS? It doesn't have to use CSS grid, it just needs to meet the requirements.

Thanks!

```css
.wrap {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(25%, 1fr) fit-content(50%) minmax(25%, 1fr);
  margin: 0 auto 20px;
}

.left,
.right {
  background: #faa;
  padding: 5px;
  
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.middle {
  background: #aaf;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="left">&lt; Left short</div>
  <div class="middle">Middle short</div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>

<div class="wrap">
  <div class="left">&lt; Left long lorem ipsum dolor sit amet elit sed ante purus tincidunt in semper sit amet vehicula ut mauris rhoncus nunc sed sapien varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes nascetur ridiculus mus</div>
  <div class="middle">Middle short</div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>

<div class="wrap">
  <div class="left">&lt; Left long lorem ipsum dolor sit amet elit sed ante purus tincidunt in semper sit amet vehicula ut mauris rhoncus nunc sed sapien varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes nascetur ridiculus mus</div>
  <div class="middle">Middle long lorem ipsum dolor sit amet elit sed ante purus tincidunt in semper sit amet vehicula ut mauris rhoncus nunc sed sapien varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes nascetur ridiculus mus</div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>

<div class="wrap">
  <div class="left">&lt; Left short</div>
  <div class="middle">Middle long lorem ipsum dolor sit amet elit sed ante purus tincidunt in semper sit amet vehicula ut mauris rhoncus nunc sed sapien varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes nascetur ridiculus mus</div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Conditions 2 and 3 are mutually exclusive. You cannot achieve your desired 25% 50% 25% while also allowing the back button to grow beyond 25%